# Excel VBA : How to increase row count one by one in every button click

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

```
Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim Name As String
Dim Age As Integer
Dim Row As Integer
Dim i As Integer
i = 2
Row = i
If (Sheet1.Range("D10").Value = "") Then
MsgBox ("Enter Value")
Else
Name = Sheet1.Range("D10").Value
Age = Sheet1.Range("D12").Value
Sheet2.Select
Sheet2.Range("A" & Row) = Name
Sheet2.Range("B" & Row) = Age
Sheet1.Range("D10").Value = ""
Sheet1.Range("D12").Value = ""
End If
End Sub
```

In the above code i want to increase Row count on every button click.
Ex : In excel Row sheet1(D10) save into Sheet2(A2)
While click on button next time value of D10 should be save into A3.

Comment: I can give you the answer but I want you to try it first ;) [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba) will get you started!

Comment: I tried with for loop but always data populated in same row

Comment: Did you add `+ 1` to the last row?

Comment: Yes i use increment (i = i+1) but after clicking on button value saved in row 2

Comment: No. You need to find the last row which has data and then add 1 to it. Find the last row as I have shown in that post :)

Answer (score 1):

`1` There is no need to use the variable `i`. Simply find the last row as shown [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba) which has data and add `1` to it for the next available row.

`2` Don't declare the row variable as `Integer`. `xl2007+` have `1048576` rows. Use `Long`.

`3` You don't have to use `.Select` to write to a sheet. Directly perform the operaton by fully qualifying the objects. You may want to see [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros/10718179#10718179)

Is this what you are trying (**UNTESTED**)?

```
Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim Name As String
    Dim Age As Integer
    Dim lRow As Long

    With Sheet2
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

        If Len(Trim(Sheet1.Range("D10").Value)) = 0 Then
            MsgBox ("Enter Value")
        Else
            Name = Sheet1.Range("D10").Value
            Age = Sheet1.Range("D12").Value

            .Range("A" & lRow) = Name
            .Range("B" & lRow) = Age

            Sheet1.Range("D10,D12").ClearContents
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Another way is using the **UsedRange** property. It gets the current range of cells with content in an individual worksheet. The exact property to add into your existing code would look like this:

```
Sheet2.UsedRange.Rows.Count
```

With only one row filled in Sheet 2, you'll get a count of 1, which wouldn't work with a +1 to the count (it will keep inserting into row 2). Add some content into that first row of Sheet 2, and then try this code:

```
Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim Name As String
Dim Age As Integer
Dim Row As Integer
Dim i As Integer

Row = Sheet2.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1
If (Sheet1.Range("D10").Value = "") Then
MsgBox ("Enter Value")
Else
Name = Sheet1.Range("D10").Value
Age = Sheet1.Range("D12").Value
Sheet2.Select
Sheet2.Range("A" & Row) = Name
Sheet2.Range("B" & Row) = Age
Sheet1.Range("D10").Value = "test"
Sheet1.Range("D12").Value = ""
End If

End Sub
```

See how you go!

If you must have that first row empty then let's look at adding some extra code to accommodate that.

Comment: - 1 for suggesting `usedrange`. Please check the link that I gave above as to why `UsedRange` shouldn't be used.